# have a problem with copy and paste

Tags: libreoffice, copy

when I try to copy ctrl+c it's not working. 
it's works only when I’m on English (Hebrew) its dosent copy / paste do any of keyboard shorts..

also what's better libreoffice or open-office?

Comment: Try this link out [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/assign-custom-shortcut-keys-on-ubuntu-linux/)

Comment: [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/187663/openoffice-vs.-libreoffice-whats-the-difference-and-which-should-you-use/) is an article on Libreoffice or open-office

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug on Ubuntu (and possibly other Linux distributions as well).
Launchpad page: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962

Possible solutions:

- Remove the libreoffice-gtk package (works, but at the cost of ugly UI)
- See comment #280 in the bug page above: it seems like the root cause is a bug in unity-settings-daemon, and a fixed version is available through a custom PPA